# MissingMethodException when trying to use PInvoke in SmartDevice project

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, pinvoke

I have compiled a native dll for windows mobile SDK, and then created c# project to call it from. However, all i get is a MissigMethodException.

Dll is in the same folder as Managed executable file.

Here is how exported functions look in header:

```
namespace cuttingStream
{
    /**
     * Открывается файл и производится его проверка.
    **/
    __declspec(dllexport) bool open_png_file(char* , pngDataStructures* );
    __declspec(dllexport) void close_png_file(pngDataStructures*);
    ...
}
```

Here is how i import them:

```
static class CuttingStreamWrapper
{
    [DllImport("libpngStreamWrap.dll", EntryPoint = "open_png_file")]
    public static extern bool OpenPngFile(string fileName, out pngDataStructures dataStruct);
    [DllImport("libpngStreamWrap.dll", EntryPoint = "close_png_file")]
    public static extern bool ClosePngFile(ref pngDataStructures dataStruct);
}
```

Here is dumpbin's output (relevant part):

```
1    0 00001340 ?close_png_file@cuttingStream@@YAXPAUpngDataStructures@@@Z
2    1 00001194 ?open_png_file@cuttingStream@@YA_NPADPAUpngDataStructures@@@Z
```

After marking functions with `extern "C"` in both source file and header, dumpbin output changed to:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00001314 close_png_file
      2    1 0000118C open_png_file
```

Which seems to be not mangled.

However, the problem remains. Here is the exception i recieve:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  Message="Не удается найти PInvoke DLL \"libpngStreamWrap.dll\"."
```

StackTrace only has the main function of a program, where i try to call wrapped function.

Update:

After running dependency walker on the dll i am trying to load, i've got 2 dependencies: Coredll.dll, msvcr90d.dll. On the device i am trying to deploy to ther is only msvcr80.dll. That explains the failure to load.

Comment: Try putting extern "C" around exports,because that looks as c++ export.

Comment: Naturally it does, seeing as that's a c++ function. What would putting extern "C" there achieve?
I did it anyway, but still got the same exception.

Comment: Pinvoke only works on C functions because c++ ones are mangled . So you should export them as  C functions or put you pinvoke EntryPoint to mangled name you got from dumpbin.

Comment: Only deploy the Release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was rooted in the dll's dependency on msvcr90d.dll, that is not found on the device. Once dependency was eliminated (by switching to /MTd from /MDd), dll was found.

Comment: A MissingMethodException can sometime be confusing becasue you'll get the same if a dependency of the P/Invoked DLL is missing (I'd rather it threw a MissingModuleException in those cases, but I didn't get to choose).